# Undefined Function jQuery

Tags: jquery

This function keeps returning as undefined I have all the values declared before hand and I also have a random number generator I've tried multiple ways but cannot seem to figure it out

```
function randomCrystalValue(){
 purpleValue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1);
 // clearValue = randomNumber(1,12);
 // greenValue = randomNumber(1,12);
 // yellowValue = randomNumber(1,12);

 $('#purple').val(purpleValue);
 console.log(purpleValue);
 // $('#clear').val(clearValue);
 // console.log(clearValue);
 // $('#green').val(greenValue);
 // console.log(greenValue);
 // $('#yellow').val(yellowValue);
 // console.log(yellowValue);
}

console.log(randomCrystalValue());
```

Comment: The function doesn't return anything.

Comment: use just `randomCrystalValue();` instead of `console.log(randomCrystalValue());`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to output the value of the function randomCrystalValue(), but that function doesn't return any value.

Maybe you want to add `return purpleValue;` to the end of your function if you want to get the value, or don't use console.log